# How to change color of logs in console for Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, logging, console

All the words and text in logs have the same color, so it is harder to look at the logs.

I would like to see something which can make the console colorful like the text in IDE, so we can easily read the logs

Btw I'm logging through `LOGGER.info`

One of my logs:

{"timestamp":"2019-07-26T15:50:20.011+05","level":"INFO","thread":"main","logger":"org.lognet.springboot.grpc.GRpcServerRunner","message":"Starting gRPC Server ...","context":"default"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*application-properties*

```
spring.main.banner-mode=off 
spring.output.ansi.enabled=ALWAYS
```

[image]

Comment: it isn't working, the banner disappeared but the text is still the same color

Comment: The normal Eclipse console doesn't support colours. What are you using here?

Comment: @PatelRomil i installed "ANSI escape" plugin and then it worked. But not for my custom logs with paranthesis